# Where might Cors be disabled?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have taken over an API project which is connected to a UI project.  The UI is an example of how to use the API.  The API is based on ASP.NET API , and the UI server is ASP.NET MVC 4 with some embedded angular.js.

I am getting errors in my API relating to CORS.

My error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myAPI. 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'my UI' is therefore not allowed access. 
The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

I am looking to debug by enabling all CORS first, then shutting down later progressively later. My code in  *App_Start/WebApiconfig.cs* on the API server.

using System.Web.Http.Cors;

```
namespace *myAPI*
{

    public static class WebApiConfig
    {

        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {

            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*",  "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);
         }
    }
}
```

Is there anything on the UI Server / Client code I need to consider? Is there anywhere else I should look to enable CORS for all sites?

Comment: a 500 is terminal.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359224/conflict-between-cors-in-web-api-microsoft-owin-cors?rq=1

Comment: Have you considered just putting a proxy behind the UI? Usually simpler than messing with CORS.